# Why don't my alert message and background color change execute simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get both my final Alert message "Congratulations..." and the HTML background color change to happen simultaneously. The color change happens *after* I click on the 'Ok' button of the already displayed Alert message. Where am I going wrong?

Admittedly, there is a similar question, though I didn't get any pointers from the suggested solutions.

```js
let myColors = ["red", "purple", "blue",
  "orange", "violet", "green",
  "amber", "olive", "navy",
  "maroon", "lime", "yellow", "chartreuse",
  "crimson", "wheat", "deeppink",
  "gold", "beige", "turquoise"
];

let yourColor = (prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + (myColors.sort()).join(", ") + "\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?")).toLowerCase();

function yourGuessedColor() {
  while (myColors.indexOf(yourColor) <= -1) {
    alert("Sorry, I don't recognize your color.\n\nPlease try again.");
    yourColor = (prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + (myColors.sort()).join(", ") + "\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?")).toLowerCase();
  }
  return yourColor;
}

let guessedColor = yourGuessedColor();
let guesses = 1;

function colorGame() {
  let myFavColor = myColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * myColors.length)];
  while (guessedColor != myFavColor) {
    if (guessedColor > myFavColor) {
      alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine.\n\nPlease try again.");
      guessedColor = (prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + (myColors.sort()).join(", ") + "\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?")).toLowerCase();
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint: your color is alphabetically lower than mine.\n\nPlease try again.");
      guessedColor = (prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + (myColors.sort()).join(", ") + "\n\nWhat color am I thinking of?")).toLowerCase();
    }
    guesses++;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = myFavColor;
  }
  return alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!\n\nIt took you " + guesses + " guesses to finish the game.\n\nYou can see the color in the background.");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Color Guessing Game</title>
</head>

<body onload="colorGame()">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because JavaScript is single-threaded, and the `alert()` pauses execution until after it's dismissed. If you used a modal dialogue instead (in the document, rather than an `alert()`) then the colour-change could happen as soon as the dialogue is shown.

Comment: Note that the OP does set the background color before alerting: `document.body.style.backgroundColor = myFavColor;` comes before `return alert("Congratulations!...` in the code.

Comment: [tag:web-worker] : Use [`WebWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers) to manage multi-threads

Comment: Can you include this codepen in your post? It simplified the issue to 3 lines of code. I wonder if this is a bug or a js "Feature"..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgypPW

Comment: Same result as my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two things going on here. As noted in the comments, Javascript is single-threaded and an alert box waits for your click before executing the next instruction. In your case, one possibility would be to simply change the color before showing the alert box:

```
                //CHANGE THE COLOR BEFORE ALERTING
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = guessedColor;
                return alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!\n\nIt took you " + guesses + " guesses to finish the game.\n\nYou can see the color in the background.");
```

But there is also something else going on here. It looks like even if you fire off the command to change the background color first, the alert box gets fired off **before** the instruction (to change the color) finishes. An alert box stops the thread in the browser, and that must include the color change instruction as well. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not. And I've only tried it in Chrome, so I'm not sure about other browsers.

One way you can get around this is to put your alert box on a delayed timer, like this:

```
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = guessedColor;
  var alertMsg = "Congratulations! You have guessed the color!\n\nIt took you " + guesses + " guesses to finish the game.\n\nYou can see the color in the background.";
  setTimeout(function(){alert(alertMsg)},100);
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzcht5dz/1/

Comment: I have actually tried that already, but with no success. The HTML background color still executes after the Alert box is gone.

Comment: I now see what you are talking about. I've not seen this before. There must be some sort of anomaly with the alert box firing BEFORE the color change completes. I'm not exactly sure why that is happening. However, you can get around it by putting the alert box on a slight delay. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: It's a very bizzare bug. I crunched it down to 3 lines of code and can replicate it every time: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wgypPW Your answer is correct on how to fix the issue. There is another question similar to this one with the fix being the set timeout. I wonder why this happens in JS???

Comment: Very strange. I do not know why this happens. At least there is a work-around.

Comment: Everything I thought I knew about the world is now wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Spinks. I'll go with your edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

The next line of your javascript will not run until after the alert box has been dismissed. Instead of using an alert() you could use console.log() which would not pause execution.

EDIT: My bad, you want the user to see it. As a commenter suggested below, simply change the background color before showing the alert().

Comment: He needs to give output to the user, though.

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` stops the script until dismissed.
Try replacing `alert()` with `display()` and define `display()` as:

```
function display(a){
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = a;
}
```

Make sure to have an element in your HTML with id `display`.